# Tomcat websocket management and identification

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, tomcat8

I am trying to implement a web socket session manager and I have just encountered a road block that I hope someone can assist me with.

Basically a client will initiate a web socket session with my websocket server endpoint and I will take the HTTP request parameters, parse it and subscribe to web service producer endpoint. The Web service will return a response containing a subscription identifier of which will use as a key mapping (along with the HTTP session ID) to add to a java map cache with the session object. The  proceed to send data to my published webservice consumer endpoint. My application will then take the data received from the producer, use the subscription id that comes with each packet and find the right session in the map caches to send the data back to.

Here is my problem..

I noticed that if the client opens another tab in the browser and sends a second subscription request, it would still be sent with the same HTTP Session ID yet tomcat will still be able to stream the data to the correct tab. This implies that the tomcat websocket implementation has a built in multiplex handling mechanism.

To exclude some unnecessary details unless asked, I want to to also be able identify all the channels that were multiplexed under the same session id. But I can't find any way in the API to identify it. As I need to be able to look up my map caches and remove sessions for tabs that have been closed (which triggers a close method in my web socket endpoint), but I'm not going to be able to do that as there could be many sockets/channels associated with the same HTTP Session ID.

Comment: not multiplex -- it's just that each tab opens a new websocket. they do share the same session because the same cookie is sent. You can use a reference counter -- how many websockets are opened for a session. if it reaches 0, you can do some cleanup work.

Comment: First off, is this reference counter you are talking about session.getId() ?thanks for your reply

Comment: you can maintain of map of `session id -> number of open websockets`. increase the number when a ws is open; decrease it when a ws is closed. it has to be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks I think i will opt for this option if the framework doesn't provide its own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The websocket framework does not provide any such implementation. Every tab opens a new socket. You can maintain a session info through adding a key in the request while initiating the websocket and on message check for that key(eg JSESSION id value) in the server and serve the request accordingly.